How to set non-uniform y-axis ticks in R ggplot2?
I am creating some plots using R ggplot2 and I have run into a challenge. I want to set non-uniform ticks on the y-axis, but I am not sure how to go about it.
eg:
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), y = c(1, 1.1, 1.9, 10, 100, 1, 1.1, 1.9, 13, 100))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() + 
    xlab(NULL) + 
    ylab(NULL)

p


Because many y axis value in range 1 to 10, I want to show more detail in this range, so I want to y axis like this:

just for example, omit the points in this plot

I'd recommend a (pseudo) log transform in such a case, using + scale_y_log10() or + scale_y_continuous(transform = "pseudo_log").

You can use scale_y_continuous and set the breaks manually or use a transformation (as suggested by @teunbrand).
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), y = c(1, 1.1, 1.9, 10, 100, 1, 1.1, 1.9, 13, 100))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() + 
    xlab(NULL) + 
    ylab(NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 10, 37, 62, 100))

p

